# OCMockObserver: unexpected notification observed

Tags: objective-c, ocmock, xctest

NotificationManager.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NotificationManager : NSObject

-(void)postNotification;

@end
```

NotificationManager.m

```
#import "NotificationManager.h"

@implementation NotificationManager

-(void)postNotification
{
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Some data" forKey:@"TestData"];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:[NSNotification notificationWithName:@"TestNotification" object:nil userInfo:userInfo]];
}

@end
```

Unit test:

```
-(void)testNotification
{
    id observerMock = [OCMockObject observerMock];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addMockObserver:observerMock name:@"TestNotification"  object:nil];

    [[observerMock expect] notificationWithName:@"TestNotification" object:[OCMArg any]];

    NotificationManager * nm= [[NotificationManager alloc]init];
    [nm postNotification];

    [observerMock verify];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:observerMock];
}
```

I get error:

**OCMockObserver: unexpected notification observed: NSConcreteNotification 0xfbbad70 {name = TestNotification; userInfo = {
    TestData = "Some data";
}}**

If I post notification without userInfo object (just nil), test works. Can someone please explain why?

Comment: This is a very well constructed question. It only took me a few seconds to recreate your issue with the code you posted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you don't specify `userInfo` it expects nil for the value. Change it to:

```
[[observerMock expect] notificationWithName:@"TestNotification" object:[OCMArg any] userInfo:[OCMArg any]];
```

It should pass.